# Java Applet Development - JavaScript code to check whether JRE is installed on client machine

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Java Applet Development - JavaScript code to check whether JRE is installed on client machine.

Comment: Please try to put a little more effort into your questions in the future. For example, by actually asking a question, and by outlining why you're asking, and what you've tried so far. And don't just copy the title into the body of the question, that's just plain lazy.

Comment: Also how about explaining why this is tagged "gwt"?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Deployment Toolkit script](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html)

use `getJREs()` by including the above javascript and  the getJREs() method returns an array of currently-installed JRE version strings .

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.javaEnabled()` will return true if java is enabled, false otherwise